# Hammer.js Swipe not working

Tags: javascript, html, hammer.js

I am trying to implement horizontal swiping using hammer.js. but I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function.

what could it be?

**Code:** https://jsfiddle.net/6d88314h/

**Function:**

```
$(function(){
    var blue = document.getElementById("blue");

    Hammer(blue).on("swipeleft", function() {
          $(blue).animate({left: "-=100"}, 500)  
    });

    Hammer(document.getElementById("blue")).on("swiperight", function() {
          $(blue).animate({left: "+=100"}, 500)  
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add jQuery to your page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```